Installing external third party theme in moodle?
Hi there tech enthusiasts and fellow developers,
I have a question from u that
How should I install and configure a third party theme into my Moodle site??
Third party means an external theme that I want to integrate into my moodle site except those themes available as a plugin for moodle.
Can anyone guide me with the steps involve??It would be very kind of you.
Thanks
I have tried making a child theme of boost but turns out it doesnot fulfill my end goal for my moodle site.
I want a proper external theme being configured and integrated into my site.

https://docs.moodle.org/404/en/Installing_plugins#Installing_a_plugin
